# How to serialize datetime value in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, datetime

I am using ASP.NET MVC5 framework to build an app. I need a function to allow me to easily convert ad object to a json string.

I found this awsome class that will do exactly what I need.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
namespace App.Support
{
    public static class JsonHelpers
    {
        public static string ToJson(this object obj)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(obj);
        }

        public static string ToJson(this object obj, int recursionDepth)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.RecursionLimit = recursionDepth;
            return serializer.Serialize(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

The only issue that I am not sure how to workaround is datetime values.

after reading a list from a database with some datetime column I want to convert the list to json. When I use JsonHelper.ToJson(mylist); the datetime fields will look like this `Date(1456182878660)`

How can I convert that value to `YYYY-MM-DD- H:i:s` format?  when I parse the json string using jQuery the datetime value looks like this `/Date(1456182878660)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) or [one of the many alternatives](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=json) instead of the 'native' JavaScriptSerializer. Newtonsoft.Json (but many others as well) allow [for much better control of the (de)serialization process](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) and many also [perform better](http://www.newtonsoft.com/content/images/jsonperformance.png). Even better: since you're doing ASP.Net, chances are the package is already installed in your project.

Comment: Will I then use this JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mylist) to convert an object to json string?

Comment: Uh, yeah. Why don't you try it? :-)